# Symbolic Mathematics for .NET

Tags: math, symbolic-math

I am looking for symbolic mathematics library for .NET framework.  I have looked at Math.net but it's not something usable yet.  Do you know if there is another library exists?

Comment: What do you find about Math.NET that isn't usable? I know several people that use it in production code to do things like symbolic math. To be honest though, I don't know of any other libraries that do it even as well as Math.NET.

Comment: Their symbolic package is old (as of 2003) and the development stopped.  Also, no documentation at all.

Answer (score 3):

This might be overkill, but you can talk to [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/index.html) from .NET, using its [.NET/Link API](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/mathlink/netlink/).

Answer (score 1):

[Symbolism](https://github.com/dharmatech/Symbolism) is a library which implements automatic simplification of algebraic expressions in C#. It can be used as a foundation for more complex symbolic mathematics operations.

Comment: Cool, I will check it out also.

Comment: @ja72 I just noticed an answer you posted on physics.stackexchange regarding projectile motion. Coincidentally, I've added some examples to Symbolism illustrating solutions to projectile motion problems. Any feedback or suggestions welcome!

Comment: @ja72 For example, [here's an example](https://github.com/dharmatech/Symbolism/blob/master/PSE%205E%20Example%204.5%20Thats%20Quite%20An%20Arm/Program.cs) and [here's the output](https://twitter.com/breatharians/status/309925003120496640/photo/1).