# Symbolic Manipulation Within .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I recall an assigment in one of my computer science classes that involved symbolic differentiation with Common Lisp. The properties of common lisp allows you to take an equation and apply symbolic manipulation.

My question is, are there any libraries and programming languages within the .Net framework that allows symbolic manipulation? I'd prefer using C# to solve this. I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770064/symbolic-mathematics-for-net) link but it doesn't give concrete answers.

Let me explain my situation in more detail.

Suppose I have conditional formula, the entirety as a String.
Each name 1DPZ_XY represents an integer variable. 
Each of these variables have already been assigned a value.

```
"
{
1DPZ_a2 = (2 OR 3)
AND
(
1DPZ_a6 = 9
OR 
1DPZ_b3 = (3 OR 7)
AND 
(
1DPZ_b4 = 8
OR
1DPZ_b5 = 2
OR
1DPZ_b6 = (4 OR 2)
)
)
}
"
```

Obviously this formula will return either true or false.
How can I convert this String logic into a if-statement I can interact with?

Comment: Why does this have an R tag?

Comment: There are some unnecessary tags, here.  Maybe drop R, Matlab and Mathematica tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse your string and build a [.NET Expression Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) from it. You can then manipulate that expression tree to evaluate it, print it, or transform it (typically using an [ExpressionVisitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx)).